# Django,Template-loader postmortem

Tags: django

Django does not see my registration.templates folder.I do not understand where the problem lies.

[image]

Why is he looking foe base.html?

This is how I specified my templates

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'store/templates/registration')],
```

My store directory

```
tree .
.
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── 0002_auto_20180604_0751.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── 0002_auto_20180604_0751.cpython-36.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── models.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
├── templates
│   ├── registration
│   │   ├── activate.html
│   │   ├── activation_complete.html
│   │   ├── activation_email_subject.txt
│   │   ├── activation_mail.txt
│   │   ├── registration_complete.html
│   │   └── registration_form.html
│   ├── store.html
│   └── template.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('store.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

Comment: It is looking for `base.html` because presumably your view is using that template? It's not very clear what you are asking here. Have you provided a `base.html` in your template directory?

Comment: No,take a look at tree.

Comment: Well that's your problem then - your view is either trying to render `base.html`, or one of your other templates is trying to extend `base.html`, but no such template exists.